# How to check in compile time that the function has default parameter value?

Tags: c++, if-constexpr

All try to do is to make this piece of code

```cpp
int main() {

    if constexpr( ??? ) {
        std::cout << "Yes\n";
        std::cout << f() << '\n';
        std::cout << f(42) << '\n';
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "No\n";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

- compile if the function `f` is defined as in any of these examples

```cpp
// Example 1
int f(int n = 0) { return n; }

// Example 2
int f(int n) { return n; }
int f() { return 0; }

// Example 3
int f(int n) { return n; }
```

- and display `Yes` for examples `1` and `2`, and display `No` for the example `3`.

Is this even possible? I think I've seen someone doing this with SFINAE but I don't remember how exactly it was done and where exactly I saw that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Yes for examples 1 and 2` so print yes if you can call `f()`, irrelevant to if there is a default parameter value?

Comment: `std::is_same_v<decltype(f()), int> && std::is_same_v<decltype(f(42)), int>` perhaps?

Comment: Which C++ version?

Comment: Justin, C++17 and higher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if constexpr` can’t protect ill-formed code **outside** of any template (*e.g.*, in `main`).  The obvious thing to do is to write a template that accepts `f` itself as a template argument, but to do that you have to **reify** your overload set.  The usual way to do that is as a **SFINAE-friendly** function object:

```
template<class F,class=void>
constexpr bool opt=false;
template<class F>
constexpr bool opt<F,decltype(std::declval<F>()(1),void(std::declval<F>()()))> =true;

template<class F> int use(F &&x) {
  if constexpr(opt<F>) return x(1)+x();
  else return 0;
}

const auto f_=[](auto &&...aa) -> decltype(f(std::forward<decltype(aa)>(aa)...))
  {return f(std::forward<decltype(aa)>(aa)...);};

int main() {use(f_);}
```

In some cases there is also the option of creating a “fake” template that uses calls that are **formally** dependent but always use the types you want, but that’s impossible for a call `f()` with no arguments, which is ill-formed (possibly with no diagnostic required) immediately if your `f` requires an argument since it can’t depend on a template parameter.

Comment: "but to do that you have to reify your overload set" – I have no problem with that, but how exactly do I change your setup so it does the exact thing that was described in the question? It's hard to wrap my mind around where exactly the business logic goes. Thank you.

Comment: @ЮкиЭндо: That’s `use`, where you have the `if constexpr` you want and can call `f` (under the name `F()`).

Comment: It took me some time to understand what exactly happens here and seems like there is something wrong. If I understand correctly, it doesn't compile because `decltype` doesn't allow lambda expressions in it. Is there any workaround? I was tweaking this example for around one hour but wasn't able to come up with something that compiles and works as intended at the same time.

Comment: @ЮкиЭндо: `decltype([]{})` is a C++20 feature, and you hadn't specified a language version at the time.  (Worse, Clang hasn't implemented it yet.)  I made a trivial edit to account for that, which also produces the local name `x` instead of `F()` for `f`.

Comment: Davis, thanks, though I actually tried that when I was tweaking the original answer, and [even with GCC + c++20](https://godbolt.org/z/rTTaoT71a) this approach doesn't seem to work. (look at the assembly line 22)

Comment: @ЮкиЭндо: Sorry, I had assumed another C++20 feature (default constructors for lambdas), and compounded it with a mistake in using `void()`.  Both fixed now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232154/discussion-between---and-davis-herring).